# TList and Creating New Class that is a List of Class of my own is updating Tlist

Tags: c#, .net, list, tlist

I have a WizardInfo class which as several TLists as properties, this then populates as the user goes through the wizard on the last screen I query the Tlists and make them into Lists and private fields
I then create Lists of DefaultItems from these lists. This is my own class and as name and Id as its property.
He is some code

```
public class DefaultItem
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
} 

private List<DefaultItem> _defaultList = null;
_defaultList = new List<DefaultItem>();
defaultValue = PopulateDefaultList(_asmgps, defaultList);
private int PopulateDefaultList(
        List<ASGMP> asmgps,
        ref List<DefaultItem> defaultList)
{
   int isdefault = -1;
   foreach (ASGMP asgmp in asgmps)
   {
      if (asgmp.IsChecked)
      {
         if (asgmp.IsDefault)
         {
            isdefault = asgmp.ID;
         }

         DefaultItem defaultItem = new DefaultItem();
         defaultItem.ID = asgmp.ID;
         defaultItem.Name = GetMPTName(asgmp.ID);  
         defaultList.Add(defaultItem);
      }
   }

   return isdefault;
}

private string GetMPTName(int ID)
{
    try
    {
        SGMP sgmp = DataRepository.SGMPProvider.GetByASGMPID(ID)
        if (serviceGroupMailPresentation != null)
        {
            MPT mpt DataRepository.MPTProvider.GetByMPTID(SGMP.MPTID);
            if (mailPresentationType != null)
            {
                return mpt.Name;
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WindowsEventLog.Write(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

The problem i am having is when i remove a item from the defaultList it affects asgmp.
**I have found the answer. When I get the mpt name I get asgmp from the database this is where Codesmith does a strange thing and connects the usage of the List and the DefaultList. By querying the original List instead of going to the database it now works fine.**

Comment: TList? In C#? That's Delphi.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary` here instead of creating this `DefaultItem` class?  This seems redundant too... `private List<DefaultItem> _defaultList = null;
_defaultList = new List<DefaultItem>();`

Comment: any chance you could ensure you're posting correct code? The overload of `PopulateDefaultList` you're calling does not match the one you've shown (the former takes 7 params, the latter 2).

Comment: sorry the extra parremeters where for nothing thats the question was about. Why is it redundent the list is past to the View to bind to a comboBox, I return the  list to a private variable and all I want know in c# why is a TList created by Codesmith and being afected by removing and item from the DefaultList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is because of ntiers instead of using the database the to get the  ID I should of used the in List of T in

Comment: You should mark this answer as solved if it says did actually solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

erm, instead of `PopulateDefaultList` why not just do,

```
var defaultList = asgmps
        .Where(asgmp => asgmp.IsChecked)
        .Select(asgmp => new
            {
                IsDefault = asgmp.IsDefault,
                Item =  new DefaultItem
                    {
                        ID = asgmp.ID,
                        Name = GetMPTName(asgmp.ID)
                    }
            }).ToList();
```

of course, naming a collection `defaultList` that contains non-defaults seems counter intuitive.

Comment: I trired that it still affects the Tlist thanks for the reponse.

Comment: @user3437405, in what way, and what is a `TList`, a `List<T>`?

Comment: @user3437405, unless `GetMPTName` returns a reference type, using the code in my answer, changes to either `asgmps` or `defaultList` cannot effect the other. Its not possible. If you are experience this behaviour your are not using this code.

Comment: No GetMptenum just gets an enum from the id of another table complelty TList Is a List created when using codesmith and NTiers

Comment: The names have been changed but the default list is made up of defaultitem that the user can choose to make default

Comment: Thats my problem Jodrell, The code you used and the one have exactly the same outcome and I dont have a clue whats causing this I was woundering if its was some kind of TList problem the causing the problem.

Comment: @user3437405, please show the code for `GetMPTName`

Answer (score 0):

It is being removed because `List<T>` is derived from `object`, and is a `Reference` type. Reference types are passed by reference, i.e. when you pass your list, you are passing a pointer to its location in memory. So any changed you make on the copied reference, will also be reflected on the original object.

In order to make a copy you can change this like:
`defaultValue = PopulateDefaultList(_asmgps, defaultList);`

to this:

`defaultValue = PopulateDefaultList(_asmgps.ToList(), defaultList);`

This will enumerate the collection as `IEnumerable<T>` and return is as a list. This will effectivlly create a copy.

Comment: Yes but the defaultList is no a TList Asgmp is derived by a query to a List from a Tlist but I create a new defaultList which is the ref not the Asgmps and new defaultItem. There should be no connection The oringinal Tlist and the DefaultItem list but when I remove an object from the DefaultItem it affects the List and the Tlists that I have used to create the List.

Comment: This is a solution for the list. Sorry. The solution for the items would be the same (more or less). You could create a constructor for `DefaultItem`, which takes an existing default item and does a `deep copy` of the data in to a new instance.

Comment: Buts thats the point i dont want the List to have any conection to the Tlist or the List I just want completley sperate objects but the way i am filling this object is causing The TList and the List to be changed. Here is the sequence I intergate Wzard Info class which as Tlists I then get datafrom those Tlists to create the List I then use the List to bind to a combo box. The main problem I have is that the Tlist is being affected by the Default List which should have no connection.